# Как закрыть окно JDialog

Tags: java, intellij-idea, swing, jframe, jdialog

Есть код:

```
 public firstMenu() {
        setTitle("Diagnostic System");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        this.setBounds(dimension.width / 2 - 200, dimension.height / 2 - 75, 400, 250);
        this.setContentPane(firstPanel);

        continueButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!(rulesRadioButton.isSelected())){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Необходимо принять соглашение", "Ошибка", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                }
                else {
                    DiagnosticSystem.firstName = inputName.getText();
                    DiagnosticSystem.lastName = inputSurname.getText();
                    dispose();
                }

            }
        }
        );
    }
```

Суть в том что необходимо было поставить

```
 setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Но теперь естественно, при закрытии окна на крестик программа продолжает свою работу, а нужно что бы закончило свою работу.

Как сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Надо было просто в класс добавить:

```java
setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHUNG_ON_CLOSE); 
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) { 
        ta.setText(tf.getText()); 
        dispose();
    }

});
```